# Show that the following function is discontinuous at the origin but possesses partial derivatives at every point, including the origin.

Tags: multivariable-calculus, partial-derivative

$$f(x,y) = 
\begin{cases}
\frac{x^3+y^3}{x-y} & \text{if } x \neq y \\
0 & \text{if } x = y
\end{cases}$$

The question says that it possesses partial derivatives at every point, but when I tried to find $f_x(a,a)$, I found out that it should not exist. Below are the steps:

$$ f_x(a,a) = \lim_{h\to 0} \frac{f(a+h,a)-f(a,a)}{h} = \lim_{h\to 0} \frac{(a+h)^3+a^3}{h^2}$$

This limit should not exist unless $a=0$.

So is the question wrong in saying that the partial derivatives exist at all the points?

Comment: You are right; the book is wrong. In fact, I imagine [this](https://books.google.com/books?id=90mk7qPAvb4C&pg=PA289&lpg=PA289&dq=%22at+every+point,+including+the+origin%22&source=bl&ots=rBdiaxvc4Z&sig=wbd8UerJ5DO5Hgf149Au5doeOFM&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi2ydXR0bzVAhWIYyYKHYEhCVMQ6AEIOzAE#v=onepage&q=%22at%20every%20point%2C%20including%20the%20origin%22&f=false) is the book you're quoting from, and it's easy to spot the author's mistake: in the second line of the solution claiming that $f(a,b)=\frac{a^3+b^3}{a-b}$, the author has in fact assumed $a\neq b$.

Comment: Yes. I am using a different book. In my book this problem is given as an exercise. It is very confusing when multiple authors make the same mistake (probably due to unverified copying from each other).

Comment: Also for $a \neq b$, there is no need to do an elaborate procedure to find the partial derivative by first principle. As in this case $f(x,y)$ is defined as an algebraic fraction in a neighbourhood of $(a,b)$ with denominator not equal to zero. So partial derivatives could be found by using rules of differentiation.